How to pass @Composable from child in Jetpack Compose
I'm trying to make plugins on Jetpack Compose and I need the child plugin to be able to set the UI in the parent screen, how to achieve this?
We can pass @Composable from parent to child but I need something like ContentPresenter
available to child plugins
@Composable
fun ChildComposable(view: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    view()
}

Is it correct to use state?
var view by remember { mutableStateOf<@Composable () -> Unit>({}) }


You haven't provided much context in your question, but in general I see two approaches to let a child Composable determine what the parent Composable should display.
Approach 1:
In the simplest form, you can just display whatever you want in the child Composable and then call that child Composable from the parent Composable:
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {
    ChildComposable()
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposable() {

    var contentIndex by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Column() {
        Button(onClick = { contentIndex++ }) {
            Text(text = "TOGGLE CONTENT")
        }
        if (contentIndex % 2 == 0) {
            Text(text = "SHOWING CONTENT A")
        }
        if (contentIndex % 2 == 1) {
            Text(text = "SHOWING CONTENT B")
        }
    }
}

Approach 2:
If you want to control from the child Composable what is shown in the parent Composable in another region of the screen, you can use the following concept:
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {

    var contentIndex by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Column() {
        ChildComposable(
          onChangeEvent = { contentIndex++ }
        )
        if (contentIndex % 2 == 0) {
            Text(text = "SHOWING CONTENT A")
        }
        if (contentIndex % 2 == 1) {
            Text(text = "SHOWING CONTENT B")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildComposable(
    onChangeEvent: () -> Unit
) {

    Column() {
        Button(onClick = { onChangeEvent() }) {
            Text(text = "TOGGLE CONTENT")
        }
    }
}

Please have a look at the official documentation about unidirectional data flow. In Jetpack Compose, data flows downwards the Composable hierarchy, while events bubble upwards the Compose hierarchy.  So you should never pass data from a child Composable to a parent Composable. Instead, the child Composable should fire an event (like onChangeParent), and then the parent Composable should update the data / content accordingly.
